# Lua ESP8266 tmr issue

Tags: lua, esp8266

Im busy working on a dimming light which my ESP-03 will control. But what I have read up on, I have a problem. Please see my code below then I will explain:

```
device_id = "553CDA2DEAC90"
query_id = ""
dim = 120

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","PASSWORD")
wifi.sta.connect()
wifi.sta.setip({ip="10.0.0.122",netmask="255.255.255.0",gateway="10.0.0.2"})

outpin = 7 --GPIO13 
gpio.mode(outpin,gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.write(outpin,gpio.LOW)
inpin = 6 --GPIO12
gpio.mode(inpin,gpio.INT,gpio.PULLUP)

function zero_cross()
    dt = 75*dim
    tmr.delay(dt)
    gpio.write(outpin,gpio.HIGH)
    tmr.delay(1)
    gpio.write(outpin,gpio.LOW)
    tmr.wdclr()
end

gpio.trig(inpin,"up",zero_cross)

function sendData()
    if(wifi.sta.status() == 5)then
        conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
        conn:connect(PORT,'IP')
        if(firstStart == 0)then
            conn:send(device_id)
            conn:send("|0|")
        else
            if(query_id == nil)then
                conn:send(device_id)
                conn:send("|0|")
                conn:send(dim)
            else
                conn:send(device_id)
                conn:send("|")
                conn:send(query_id)
                conn:send("|")
                conn:send(dim)
                query_id = nil
            end
        end
        conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
            payload = string.gsub(payload, " ", "")
            dim = string.sub(payload, 0, string.find(payload, "|")-1)
            payload = string.gsub(payload, dim.."|", "")
            query_id = payload
            conn:close()
        end)
    else
        wifi.sta.connect()
    end
end
tmr.alarm(6, 1000, 1, sendData )
```

The problem that I am facing is that when at the bottom of the script I start tmr.alarm()... But the under the function zero_cross() its uses tmr.delay and that seems to make tmr.alarm() not function anymore. All that happens is the ESP just keeps on restarting. If I run the above code seperate (just the dimming function or just the sendData function then everything works perfect). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nodemcu call lua callback [directly from hardware interrupt](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/tmr.c#L114), while the need to use [luahook](https://github.com/elua/elua/blob/master/src/elua_int.c), (As Lua doesn’t have direct support for interrupts, they have to be emulated). It is probably dangerous.

Solution: use only 1 interrupt same time:

```
local send_time, last_gpio
last_gpio = gpio.read(6)
send_time = 0

tmr.trigger(1, 10, 1, function()
    if (gpio.read(6) == 1 and last_gpio == 0) then
        last_gpio = 1
        zero_cross()
    else if (gpio.read(6) == 0 and last_gpio == 1)
        last_gpio = 0
    end

    send_time = send_time + 1

    if (send_time > 100) then
        send_data()
    end
end)
```